# Why would WebGL available extensions be different?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In my code, I'm doing a check for available WebGL extensions.

```
console.log(GL.getSupportedExtensions());
```

Which returns an array with 9 extensions.

[image]

But when I check my extensions with a site like [RenderingPipeline](http://renderingpipeline.com/webgl-extension-viewer/), I see many more extensions.

[image: RenderingPipeline List]

Why is there such a difference? Same machine, same browser.

Comment: You get 9 extensions from a webgl2 context.  27 from webgl1 context.

Comment: But why would simply doing GL.getSupportedExtensions() before initializing my library impact which context?

Answer (score -2):

So I was doing that check AFTER I initialized my threejs renderer -- which resulted in only 9 extensions being found or made available. I left that code in place.

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
});
```

I added an extension check BEFORE my renderer init and it returned all 27 available. Not only that but my check AFTER my renderer init now returns all 27!

Dafuq.